# Rolling up data in SAS

Tags: sas

Here is my data :

```
data example;
   input id sports_name;
   datalines;
   1 baseball
   1 basketball
   1 cricket
   1 soccer
   2 golf
   2 fencing
```

This is just a sample. The variable sports_name is categorical with 56 types. 
I am trying to transpose the data to wide form where each row would have a user_id and the names of sports as the variables with values being 1/0 indicating Presence or absence.

So far, I used proc freq procedure to get the cross tabulated frequency table and put that in a different data set and then transposed that data. Now i have missing values in some  cases and count of the sports in rest of the cases.

Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Show all your code and the current results you are getting.  Provide some example user ids as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to create something from nothing.  You could have also used the SPARSE option in PROC FREQ.  SAS names cannot have length greater than 32.

```
data example;
   input id sports_name :$16.;
   retain y 1;
   datalines;
   1 baseball
   1 basketball
   1 cricket
   1 soccer
   2 golf
   2 fencing
;;;;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=example nway completetypes;
   class id sports_name;
   output out=freq(drop=_type_);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=freq out=wide(drop=_name_);
   by id;
   var _freq_;
   id sports_name;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same theory here, generate a list of all possible combinations using SQL instead of Proc Summary and then transposing the results.

```
data example;
informat sports_name $20.;
   input id sports_name $;
   datalines;
   1 baseball
   1 basketball
   1 cricket
   1 soccer
   2 golf
   2 fencing
;
run;

proc sql;
create table complete as
select a.id, a_x.sports_name, case when not missing(e.sports_name) then 1 else 0 end as Present
from (select distinct ID from example) a
cross join (select distinct sports_name from example) a_x
full join example as e
on e.id=a.id
and e.sports_name=a_x.sports_name;
quit;

proc transpose data=complete out=want;
by id;
id sports_name;
var Present;
run;
```